# NSURLSession didBecomeInvalid usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

Apple's [docs on `NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i-CH2-SW42) state that you have to explicitly invalidate your session so it releases its strong delegate reference, or else you leak memory. So I'm calling `finishTasksAndInvalidate` in `didCompleteWithError`. Should I also invalidate it if `didBecomeInvalid` gets called with a non-nil error with a code other than -999 (cancelled)? Or does `didBecomeInvalid` only ever get called after I've explicitly invalidated the session?